# CSS - Default scrollbar display property

Tags: css

I have an ASP.Net Web Forms application that has the following CSS defined in a master stylesheet:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

I'm working on a new page that pops up a modal dialog that will sometimes have vertical overflow. In this case, I need the scrollbar to be displayed for my overflow `div`. However, I can't find a default `display` property for `::webkit-scrollbar` that resets the scrollbar to its original display state. I tried `unset` and `initial` unsuccessfully.

I also tried adding a `.scroll` class to the div I need the scrollbar to display for, and then changing the master CSS to:

```
:not(.scroll) ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

But that didn't work either. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try ::-webkit-scrollbar { visibility: visible; } ?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `overflow:hidden;` and `overflow:visible;`? Doing it this way will only affect webkit browsers, all other browsers will still show the scrollbar.

Comment: @holden i added that to my page CSS and it's still not visible for some reason

Comment: @APAD1 i am using those but i want all scrollbars hidden through all pages except this div... the overflow is still happening but i need to actually see the scrollbar in this one case

Comment: using !important rule?

Comment: @aquemini that's exactly what `overflow:hidden;` and `overflow:scroll;` are for. Just make sure that the hidden/visible elements are siblings.

Comment: @holden yes... i tried all the other `visibility` properties too

Comment: @APAD1 no because i still need the content to be scrollable in the rest of the application, just without the scrollbar visible for aesthetics... `overflow: hidden` just clips it and hides the rest which is not suitable

Comment: as a side note, I set my system preferences to always show the scroll bar (and I generally use Firefox), so make sure your design still looks ok with the scrollbar.  You won't be able to hide it in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.hideThumb::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { /* we apply the style to actually hide it*/
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: i need the opposite of this though, because i don't want to add a `hideThumb` class to every page in the app. i want to blanket hide it but only show it in this particular case